# binding more than two property in fxml

Tags: javafx, fxml, property-binding

Suppose I want to bind disable property of a button with a checkbox's selected property. I know this method to bind them in `FXML`:

```
<Button disable="${firstcheckbox.selected}"/>
```

But what if I have two checkboxes and I want to bind the button's disable property with both the checkbox's selected property. Yes, I know I can do that in my java controller but I was just wondering if there is a way to do that in `FXML`.

If it's not clear what did I want, this is the Java code alternative to what I actually wanted:

```
mybutton.disableProperty().bind(firstcheckbox.selectedProperty().and(secondcheckbox.selectedProperty()));
```

Now I want to do this in `FXML` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding), you can use the operator `&&` in expression binding.

Since the `&` character has special meaning in XML, you need to properly escape it: one way is to use `&amp;` to represent a single `&` character.

```xml
<Button disable="${firstcheckbox.selected &amp;&amp; secondcheckbox.selected}"/>
```